# Confusion matrix with a Keras Model: A question, perhaps does anybody know how to do a confusion matrix for this model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, keras, confusion-matrix

I am currently doing a research for a problem of classification, but I don't know how to make a confusion matrix for this model, which I send the code below.
I am using Keras library on collab, because my local environment was not compatible with tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory,  I get a good percentage of accuracy, and good predictions but I am lost when I am doing the matrix.
Thank in advance to the community

```
image_size = (180, 180)
batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Collab Notebooks/LungCells/seg_train",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=42,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Collab Notebooks/LungCells/seg_train",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    #seed=1337,
    seed=42,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)

data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.1),
    ]
)

def make_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Image augmentation block
    x = data_augmentation(inputs)

    # Entry block
    x = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0 / 255)(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside residual

    for size in [128, 256, 512, 728]:
        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(size, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(size, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)

        # Project residual
        residual = layers.Conv2D(size, 1, strides=2, padding="same")(
            previous_block_activation
        )
        x = layers.add([x, residual])  # Add back residual
        previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside next residual

    x = layers.SeparableConv2D(1024, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    if num_classes == 2:
        activation = "sigmoid"
        units = 1
    else:
        activation = "softmax"
        units = num_classes

    x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)


model = make_model(input_shape=image_size + (3,), num_classes=2)
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)

epochs = 50
callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("save_at_{epoch}.h5"),
]
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3),
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
model.fit(
    train_ds, epochs=epochs, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=val_ds,
)
```

Comment: what's the main problem? Can't you get confusion matrix or can't save the plot file?

Comment: I can't get the matrix, so far my best result was this:

`Y_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator , num_of_test_samples // batch_size+1)

y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)

print('Confusion Matrix')

print(confusion_matrix(validation_generator .classes, y_pred))

print('Classification Report')

target_names = ['cancer', 'no_cancer']

print(classification_report(validation_generator.classes, y_pred, target_names=target_names))`

Comment: Do u mean that you can't compute the confusion matrix for binary classification? If so, what's the error?

Comment: with this I get a small matrix but looks like the output is different than expected, so I know I am failing at some input.
I will share the results on github so it is easier to look at the results. I am trying to make the second method works for making the matrix on seaborn

Comment: This is my github
https://github.com/macwolfz/DZDeepLearningCancerClassification/blob/main/ModeloKerasLabCollab.ipynb

Comment: Have you tried simply `model.predict(validation_generator)` - no step size.

Comment: Accuray becomes good that doesn't mean your classification report would be good. There is a strong reason to be bad.

Comment: try to calculate your step size `val_steps_size = numpy.math.ceil(val_generator.samples / val_generator.batch_size)`

Comment: thank you for the help, I will try it.
I am new to this so it is still not yet that clear to me. 
where would this go, at the moment of compile: `val_steps_size = numpy.math.ceil(val_generator.samples / val_generator.batch_size)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe I fully don't understand your exact problem. But here is a similar working example that might come to you helpful.

Let's say I will train a model on `MNIST` as a binary classifier (same as yours), whether a digit is `odd` or `even` and following by `confusion matrix` and `classification report` on them.

**DataSet**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

(xtrain, ytrain), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# 2 categories, if the digit is odd or not
xtrain = np.expand_dims(xtrain, axis=-1)
xtrain = np.repeat(xtrain, 3, axis=-1)
xtrain = xtrain.astype('float32') / 255

# label 
ytrain = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical((ytrain % 2 == 0).astype(int), 
                                        num_classes=2)

print(xtrain.shape, ytrain.shape)
(60000, 28, 28, 3) (60000, 2)
```

**Model**

```
# declare input shape 
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28,28,3))
# Block 1
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=2, activation="relu")(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3)(x)

# Now that we apply global max pooling.
gap = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)

# Finally, we add a classification layer.
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(gap)

# bind all
model = tf.keras.Model(input, output)
```

**Compile and Run**

```
model.compile(
          loss      = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics   = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
          optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
# fit 
model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, batch_size=128, epochs=3, verbose = 2)
```

**Classification Report**

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

# as I've trained my model on MNIST as odd or even (binary classes)
target_names = ['odd', 'even']

# get predict prob and label 
ypred = model.predict(xtrain, verbose=1)
ypred = np.argmax(ypred, axis=1)

print(classification_report(np.argmax(ytrain, axis=1), ypred, target_names=target_names))

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         odd       0.80      0.72      0.75     30508
        even       0.73      0.81      0.77     29492

    accuracy                           0.76     60000
   macro avg       0.77      0.76      0.76     60000
weighted avg       0.77      0.76      0.76     60000
```

**Confusion Matrix**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd 

cm = confusion_matrix(np.argmax(ytrain, axis=1), ypred)
cm = pd.DataFrame(cm, range(2),range(2))
plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))

sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 12}) # font size
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i once made a confusion matrix manually by plugging inputs into the model with a for loop and then comparing the predicted outputs to the actual outputs. If the model predicted the same output as the actual output then True Positive had one added to it and vice versa.

Comment: thank you for the idea, and yes, I made that too, and I get how many predicted well, and how many failed.
but I'd like to make that matrix for analyse the result